# MySQL: Finding rows with conflicting date ranges

Tags: mysql, date, range

I'm writing an ad booking system for our site. Ads are booked in with a `StartDate` and `EndDate` field to indicate how long they're online for.

When adding a new advert, I have a quick validation check to make sure the new ad doesn't clash with an existing ad that's booked into the same position.

I thought I had it with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM adverts 
WHERE EndDate >= '2010-04-22' 
AND StartDate < '2010-04-22'
```

2010-4-22 is the `StartDate` for the new advert I want to book. There is an advert already booked in whose `StartDate` is 2010-04-26 and `EndDate` is 2010-05-09.

These are the results of the query with different dates:

---

- try to book an ad starting AFTER the existing ad ends: **returns 0 rows (correct)**
- try to book an ad starting and ending DURING the existing ad's date range: **returns 1 row (correct)**
- try to book an ad starting and ending BEFORE the existing ad begins: **returns 0 rows 
  (correct)**
- try to book an ad starting BEFORE the existing ad starts, and enduring DURING the existing ad's date range: **returns 0 rows (incorrect)**
- try to book an ad starting BEFORE and ending AFTER the current ad ends: **returns 0 rows (incorrect!)**

---

Does anybody have any ideas how to rewrite this query so I can make sure it only picks up clashes in the date ranges?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM adverts
 WHERE `EndDate` >= :AdStartDate
   AND `StartDate` <= :AdEndDate
```

I haven't accounted for the edge case where start and end dates are equal, since I don't know what your rules are for that.

Comment: This looks like the solution - I swore I tried that to start with, guess I got my logic confused. Thanks! My rules for start/end dates are the same, but this code caters for that case anyway - it returns 1 row like it should. Thank you!